# 403- Forbidden BASIC AUTHENTICATION with WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm having trouble configuring **BASIC AUTHENTICATION** with *WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0*, specifically encountering a `403 Forbidden` error. I would like to understand where the issue lies. Let me briefly explain what I have done:

I started by creating the user "**user**" in the "**Users and Groups**" section under the "**Users**" tab.

User tab User

[image]

User group
[image]

Then, I created a group called "**usergroup**" in the "**Groups**" tab.
[image]
After that, in the "**Roles and Policies >> Realm Roles**" section, I added the role condition for the consumer as "**group: usergroup**".

Roles
[image]
web.xml:

```
 <security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>webservice</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/service/test</url-pattern>
          <http-method>GET</http-method>
       </web-resource-collection>
 
       <auth-constraint>
          <role-name>consumer</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
 
   <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>default</realm-name>
   </login-config>
   <security-role>
      <role-name>consumer</role-name>
   </security-role>
```

weblogic.xml:

```
   <security-role-assignment>
      <role-name>consumer</role-name>
      <principal-name>usergroup</principal-name>
   </security-role-assignment>
```